# Leapp always fails upgrade: more space needed

Tags: centos, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade a SL/Centos 7.9 to AlmaLinux with Leap. I followed the [instructions here](https://linuxiac.com/centos-7-to-almalinux-8-migration-guide/) but it always fails with

```
At least 3178MB more space needed on the / filesystem.
```

I'm increased the disk size by 5Gb and then another 5G but the message is identical. I've also set `export LEAPP_OVL_SIZE=3000` according to some info, and then some more. No change.

```
$ df -h 
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs             809M     0  809M   0% /dev
tmpfs                825M     0  825M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                825M  9,1M  816M   2% /run
tmpfs                825M     0  825M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/sl-root   24G   15G  9,4G  61% /
tmpfs                825M   16K  825M   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1            497M  138M  360M  28% /boot
tmpfs                165M   48K  165M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Any idea what I can try next ?

Comment: Hello @dargaud I have a similar case, moving from Oracle Linux 7 to 8. It tells me that 30 MB are missing.

I see that the usual recommendation is to run export LEAPP_OVL_SIZE=8192, only in my case it makes no difference; I have the same error.

I have moved the /var/lib/leapp folder to the root, /leapp then made a symbolic link; executed and got the same error.

I have removed previous kernels, deleted logs older than 2 days, uninstall unneeded packages and still have the same message with the 30 MB.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into similar issues, in my case I tried setting the export LEAPP_OVL_SIZE parameter etc, but in the end it was the filesystem mounted on /var/lib that was not large enough.

The / filesystem had > 25Gb of free space so I did the following:
First:

cd /var/lib

mv leapp /

ln -s /leapp

This way, using a symbolic link, /var/lib/leapp was large enough to be able to upgrade my system.

Comment: Thanks, but I won't be able to test it, I eventually did a fresh install.

Comment: In my case (I am moving from Oracle Linux 7 to 8) the value of LEAPP_OVL_SIZE seems not to affect, /root has 90% of free space (more than 400 GB) and still it keeps indicating that space is missing.
I have already added more space to /root, uninstalled packages, relocated the folder and created the link, modified the LEAPP_OVL_SIZE parameter etc... but when I try to update I get the same message. I need 30 MB of free space.